# ToolTip Concept In LWUIT in J2ME

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

I have a J2ME Application in which i have four image buttons.While Focus on Each Image Button i want to show what does this image means.So,how to use concept of Tooltip in LWUIT(J2ME)?

Comment: Can anyone answer to this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a label to which you set the text on focus events. Generally tooltips are a desktop concept and not a mobile concept. Furthermore focus events don't make much sense on a touch based device so you would be hardcoding your application to feature phones and old blackberries.

Comment: Shai:Thanks alot for your help but problem is already solved and i did the same what you have mentioned.thanks for your reply.